# reference request: unbounded operators on normed spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory

I'm looking for books where the theory (basic properties, adjoints etc.) of unbounded linear operators between locally convex spaces or at least Banach spaces is developed. In Brezis' *functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and partial differential equations* there are some limited results for the Banach space case and all other related books I found only treat such operators on Hilbert spaces.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The second volume of Köthe’s “Topological vector spaces”  has about 50 pages on non-continuous linear mappings between locally convex spaces ($$ 35-38).

Comment: @user131781 thank you for this reference!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use: Goldberg, Seymour Unbounded linear operators. Theory and applications. Reprint of the 1985 corrected edition [MR0810617]. Dover Publications, Inc., Mineola, NY, 2006. viii+199 pp. ISBN: 0-486-45331-6